# Is there an alternative to window.performance for Node, if one exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am configuring Angular Universal with the intent of rendering a static site, however I'm running into some configuration issues due to components in use - such as Phaser.js.

The library is meant for browser-side, and contains a lot of window. calls. I got past a lot of the checks, but now I'm hitting "performance" issues with errors like

```
E:\Node\Angular\packetpop-static\dist\server\main.js:45668
    if (performance.timing && performance.timing.navigationStart)
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'timing' of undefined
```

I have domino installed, and it seems to work for 'window', but I'm not sure how to work around 'performance'. This is what I have tried so far:

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');



const template = fs.readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'index.html')).toString();

const window = domino.createWindow(template);

global['window'] = window;
global['document'] = window.document;
global['performance'] = window.performance;
global['performance.timing'] = window.performance.timing;
```

What else can I do?

Comment: You could try setting `global['performance'] = {}` since the library seems to check for `performance.timing`'s existence.

Comment: It seems you will have to actually load the module that the performance timing API is in for node.js and hook up the actual methods for it on the `window` object: https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html.  It does not live on a `window` object in nodejs by default.

Comment: global['performance'] = {} worked, but now it's throwing additional errors off such as "Element" and "Element.prototype.closest".

Answer (score 0):

I use this function in Node which has been useful for performance stuff

```
const elapsed_time = function(note){
    var precision = 3; // 3 decimal places
    var elapsed = process.hrtime(start)[1] / 1000000; // divide by a million to get nano to milli
    var timestampString = `#### TIMESTAMP: ${process.hrtime(start)[0]} sec, ${elapsed.toFixed(precision)} ms FROM LAST MARK: ${note}`; 
    console.log(timestampString); // print message + time
    start = process.hrtime(); // reset the timer
};
```